# Android game java boolean solution

Tags: java, android, boolean

What I'm trying to do is, making a game object move slower when a certain score is reached. I'm trying to do so with the help of boolean.

There´s the score.

```
public boolean bol = false;
```

And there´s my bool.

```
if(score == 2) {
        bol = true;
}
```

Here´s the statement.

```
if(gw.bol = true) {
        acceleration = new Vector2(0, 200);
}
```

And if bol is true (which it will be when the user reaches the score 2?) then should the acceleration became that new one I wrote?

But when I run the code I get:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.kilobolt.GameObjects.Bird.<init>(Bird.java:31)
at com.kilobolt.GameWorld.GameWorld.<init>(GameWorld.java:32)
at com.kilobolt.Screens.GameScreen.<init>(GameScreen.java:25)
at com.kilobolt.ZombieBird.ZBGame.create(ZBGame.java:13)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

Comment: This will probably not solve your problem, but `if(gw.bol = true)` should be `if(gw.bol == true)`, or even better `if(gw.bol)`

Comment: probably gw is not initialized and therefore gw.bol causes NullpointerException.

Answer (score 2):

This should be `==` instead of `=`

```
if(gw.bol == true)
```

or you could just do

```
if(gw.bol)
```

That may be the issue.